# Apache Pig, adding values for an id from different columns

Tags: apache-pig

I have loaded 3 tables for 3 subjects in PIG, each having Name:chararray and score:float.
The same name may not occur necessarily in all subjects.

I need to add the scores from the 3 tables into a single one, having Name and Total score.

I used to do this in SQL using nested queries.
How to do this in PIG?
I tried using full outer join, but was stuck after encountering null values in the Name columns for the subjects in which the name doesn't exist.

Comment: Could you please post what you have tried? A full outer `JOIN` is a possible approach here, but you will have to massage the output a bit after the `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the description of your problem, a simple `UNION` of the 3 files, followed by a `GROUP BY` should produce the results you're looking for.

---

### Example Code:


union_example.pig

```
data_1 = LOAD 'union1.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (name:chararray,score:float);
data_2 = LOAD 'union2.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (name:chararray,score:float);
data_3 = LOAD 'union3.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (name:chararray,score:float);

data = UNION data_1,data_2,data_3;

data_grp = GROUP data BY name;

data_gen = FOREACH data_grp GENERATE group, SUM(data.score);

dump data_gen;
```

---

### Datasets:


union1.csv

```
bob,3
elvis,4
jim,4
dave,2
sneech,4
suess,3
giri,5
```

union2.csv

```
mike,2
rick,3
jim,3
giri,4
dave,3
elvis,5
```

union3.csv

```
bob,5
bing,4
suess,4
sneech,5
dave,4
jim,2
giri,2
```

---

### Results:

```
(bob,8.0)
(jim,9.0)
(bing,4.0)
(dave,9.0)
(giri,11.0)
(mike,2.0)
(rick,3.0)
(elvis,9.0)
(suess,7.0)
(sneech,9.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Though you can do this using an outer [`JOIN`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/basic.html#join-outer), I think that [`UNION`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/basic.html#union)ing all of the tables together and then [`GROUP`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/basic.html#GROUP)ing by the `Name` field will be easier.

```
-- T1, T2, and T3 are the tables you have loaded.  Each has the schema 
-- TX: (Name: chararray, score: float)

F = UNION T1, T2, T3;

-- Even if the name appears in only one table, then the result of GROUP will only
-- have one item in the bag. This means we can use SUM regardless of how many tables
-- the name is in.
G = GROUP F BY Name;

H = FOREACH G GENERATE group AS Name, SUM(F.score) AS totalscore;
```

Comment: The question was up for 7 hours, but our posts were only 14 seconds apart, with the same answer!

Comment: Haha, yeah I was a little surprised when I saw the new answer thing popup. You don't usually worry about things like this on the slow(er) tags. :)